# Modern command line file compression utilities

Tags: compression, tar, rar, gzip, bzip2

I am frequently moving large files around from server to server.

UNIXes comes with standard gzip and bzip2 compressors. However, what open options there exist beyond these, especially ones utilizing multiple cores? I am aware of pzip2 which I am using currently.

Are there any up-to-date benchmarks and charts how fast/effective compressors are to see what's the tradeoff between time and the file size?

An open source alternative, which is distribution packaged and supported across Linux/OSX, preferred. Windows support unneeded.

Comment: When you say pzip2, I assume you mean pbzip2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say much about your priorities, but it sounds like compression time for large files is your main priority?

This claims to be suited to that case (see the -l flag):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/lrzip.1.html

On the other end of the tradeoff (high compression ratio, long compression time), some notable software distributions have started using this recently:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz

http://tukaani.org/xz/

Re benchmarking: why not run some quick tests youself?  Benchmarks are often misleading because results can vary a lot depending on the precise workload and test conditions.  Still, here's a report in German (try google translate) about somebody else's benchmarking:

http://www.linux-community.de/Internal/Artikel/Print-Artikel/LinuxUser/2010/10/Aktuelle-Komprimierprogramme-in-der-Uebersicht/(printView)/true

Answer (score 1):

Also worth looking at are [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) for parallelism and [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) if Windows support does rear its head.